# NFT drop marketplace Smart Contract and show collections by type

Tags: smartcontracts, nft, drop, erc721

New to NFT and solidity, and want to know how we can get NFTs grouped by collection type.
e.g.

```
collections => 
   [
    art => [nft1, nft2, ...],
    music => [nft1, nft2, ...]
   ]
```

So that users can see collections and **buy** a random NFT from it.

My question is, where to put that logic ?
in **smart contract** or we have to save nfts in other database (**MySql**, **MongoDb**) where can query and categorise them on the basis of collection type ?

If I have to do this in other database e.g. MySql, MongoDb then I will listen to transfer event when an NFT is minted and save all details on database and then query to list collections on the basis of types.

Or If I add that logic in Smart Contract then I can create Collection struct and add functions to add/remove/move NFT to that collection.

What do you think one is better option to do this ?

If smart contract is better then, how I can get collections along with NFTs added in them ?
should I create mapping of collections and then each Collection struct will have mapping of NFT struct ?